# X++ Append Text to String

Tags: axapta, x++

I currently have a method that appends two strings together based on the tag in an XML file that is being loaded.  I would also like to add a unique key between these two strings for parsing reasons later. Below are examples of the way it is working now and what I would like it to do.

```
-CURRENT: strValue~&elem.text()~& 
-GOAL: strValue~&elem.text()

// If the tag is "Tag" or "Building append its text to strValue (part of item name)
        elem = elemTag.selectSingleNode("ofda:Type",nsmgr);

        if(elem && (elem.text() == "Tag" || elem.text() == "Building"))
        {
            elem = elemTag.selectSingleNode("ofda:Value",nsmgr);
            if(elem)
            {
                strValue += elem.text() + "~&";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `strValue += elem.text();`?

Comment: strValue += elem.text() would work to get the strings appended together, but wont add a unique key in between the two strings.

Comment: Then put the uniqe value in between (guid or whatever).

Comment: Tried putting the key between "strValue + "~&" += elem.text() ;" but this throws a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

`strValue += strValue ? "~&" + elem.text() : elem.text();` ?

Comment: Resulted in "strValue elem.text()" without any key in between.

Comment: Between what and what? If strValue is not empty there will certainly be "~&" between strValue and elem.text()

Comment: "strValue += strValue ? "~&" + elem.text() : elem.text();" Using this concatenated the two strings, but did not place the ~& key in between the two strings.